# Multiple ifelse for one column mutate

Tags: r, if-statement

Trying to add just one column based on value from an existing column:

```
mutate(df, newcolumn = ifelse(DEST == c("JFK", "EWR", "LGA"), "NYC", DEST),
            newcolumn = ifelse(DEST == c("ORD", "MDW"), "CHI", DEST))
```

By do this, R would ignore the first ifelse statement, which only mutate new column with rows that satisfy the second requirement.

So do I change to satisfy both requirements?

Comment: Try replacing ```==``` with ```%in%```, so ```mutate(df, newcolumn = ifelse(DEST %in%c("JFK", "EWR", "LGA"), "NYC", DEST), newcolumn = ifelse(DEST %in% c("ORD", "MDW"), "CHI", DEST))```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `case_when` to replace both `ifelse` in one:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- mutate(df, 
             newcolumn = case_when(DEST %in% c("JFK", "EWR", "LGA") ~ "NYC",
                                   DEST %in% c("ORD", "MDW")        ~ "CHI",
                                   TRUE                             ~ DEST))
```

---

Check out `?case_when` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

We need `%in%` instead of `==`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- mutate(df, newcolumn = ifelse(DEST %in% c("JFK", "EWR", "LGA"), 
          "NYC", DEST),
        newcolumn = ifelse(DEST %in% c("ORD", "MDW"), "CHI", DEST))
```

Comment: Isn't your first assignment to `newcolumn` overwritten by the second?

Comment: Yeah same issue here.

Comment: the second `ifelse` should be: `ifelse(newcolumn %in% c("ORD", "MDW"), "CHI", newcolumn)`

Comment: @Edo It is based on the OP's code.  The OP didn't show any input example or expected output.  So, I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more conditions, you could use `case_when()` as well.

```
library(dplyr)

mutate(df, newcolumn = case_when( DEST %in% c("JFK", "EWR", "LGA") ~ "NYC",
                                  DEST %in% c("ORD", "MDW"), "CHI") ~ "CHI",
                                  TRUE ~ DEST)
```

Comment: (same answer at the same time ahah)